# css tab bar height issue

Tags: html, css

I try to implement a tab bar with extra padding on hover state.
But the problem is on hover state actually it moves parent div.

You can see the html below;

```
<div id="statNav">
        <a href="#">Gogus</a>
        <a href="#">Kol</a>
        <a href="#">Gogus</a>
        <a href="#">Gogus</a>
        <a href="#">Gogus</a>
        <a href="#">Omuz</a>
        <a href="#">Gogus</a>
</div>
```

and css;

```
#statNav{
    width:100%;
    border-bottom:2px solid #9B2F2C;
    overflow:auto;
}

#statNav a{
    float:left;
    background-color:#333333;
    color:white;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    width:62px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    border-right: 1px solid #777777;
}

#statNav a:first-child{

    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#statNav a:last-child{

    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
    border-right:none;
    width:63px;
}

#statNav a:hover{

    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    background-color:#9B2F2C;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
```

Here is the working sample;

http://jsfiddle.net/Kg3p4/

How can i solve it?

Comment: This is because you increase the height of the <a> tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this by using margins on the non-hovered tabs and removing them on hover to counter the increased padding size. Note that the size of the margins is equal to the difference between your hovered and non-hovered padding.

```
#statNav a{
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
#statNav a:hover{
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
```

I've updated your jsFiddle with a [simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Kg3p4/7/) of this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the hover state a bit by adding a negative margin-bottom equal to the padding difference. Something like this :

```
#statNav a:hover{

    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    background-color:#9B2F2C;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kg3p4/5/